# Unable to see ethernet NIC interface in Ubuntu 20.04 even though NIC is present and has physically linked up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, network-interface, ethernet

I am unable to see my ethernet card ports in the OS (Ubuntu 20.04) by doing ***ip a***. I can see the card in ***lspci*** and also under ***lshw***. I know (from BIOS menu) that a port in the Card is also connected.

How do I see the network interface actually link up in the OS? Is this a bug with Ubuntu? I have physically verified that the Port on the card is up and blinking.

[image]

[image: rk]

Comment: Just for the record, `modprobe tg3` does not claim the device. A note: if at all possible, please include the **text** output of commands instead of an image.

Comment: How do i get a driver to claim the device? Do I need to download and install the driver manually? i dont know where to get the driver... I dont have connectivity so i can even use `apt-get` for anything

Comment: Yes, you need a driver. But one of the already installed should do the trick. Could you please remove `tg3`, insert it again and show the last lines of `dmesg`? `sudo rmmod tg3;sudo modprobe tg3;sudo dmesg`. We might have overlooked something.

Comment: I found that SRIOV was not enabled in BIOS, the memory space for thecard in lspci was not being assigned. Now it is working. This works fine in RHEL (even if disabled in BIOS), seems something quirky with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! You might also answer your own question, so that other people will have the solution right away without going through the comments.